# How do I change the Japanese input tooltip dictionary?

Tags: macos, dictionary, input-source, japanese

How do I change the Japanese input tooltip dictionary from Jpn-Jpn to Jpn-Eng?

[image]

Comment: My hunch is that there is a way to have the IME use another dictionary by changing a settings file somewhere. So far I've skimmed `/System/Library/Input Methods/JapaneseIM-RomajiTyping.app` and `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreJapaneseEngine.framework/Versions/A` and looked for 'dictionary' or 'candidate' (the input tooltip is called candidate window), but I'm not familiar with these applications.